# Unicode version of InternetOpenUrl returns error 12002

Tags: c++, unicode, wininet

Basically I am converting my program from multibyte to unicode so that I can advertise it commercial to people in other countries as well (basically its a live stream application). I've been experiencing many issues during this conversion. But recently, I've ran into one that's just been tearing my eyes open.

I have the following code (including the function from `Remy Lebeau`'s answer):

```
void get_user_request(const wchar_t *url)
{
    LPVOID hi, hu;

    hi = InternetOpenW(SUBSCRIBER_USER_AGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    if(hi==NULL)
    {
        WinInetError(L"InternetOpenW");
    }
    else
    {
        hu = InternetOpenUrlW(hi, url, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

        if(hu==NULL)
        {
           WinInetError("InternetOpenUrlW");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxW ( 0, "We're in", 0, 0 );
            InternetCloseHandle(hu);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hi);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 START**

I call the function like so:

```
get_user_request(request_url);
```

where `request_url` is:

```
WCHAR *request_url; // its a global variable
request_url = L"http://example-site.com/user/<user-id>/";
```

I assign the value by concatenating the strings necessary for the request into it, the concatenation is somewhat like this:

```
wsprintfW ( request_url, L"?id=%s", string);
```

Prior to this concatenation. `request_url` is also concatenated to wstring like so: `lstrcatW(request_url, myWString.c_Str());`

**EDIT 1 END**

Basically, before my conversion to unicode; this function worked fine. After the conversion. I get the following error on the `hu = InternetOpenUrlW()` line:

Setting a breakpoint right after returns `error 12002` - after looking this error up the description from MSDN is as follows:

`12002       ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT
               The request has timed out.`

If the request timed out, i assumed that the url passed to the function may have been malformed somehow. After that I inserted a breakpoint in my windows debugger at that parameter. It appears that the only string that is passed to that parameter is `'h'` ... That is strange because I look back in my code and i pass the entire url to the function as a `const wchar_t*` just as it takes according to my paramter.

After that, I inserted the `MessageBoxW()` to show me the value of the `url` string that is passed to the function, just before. The output (surprisingly enough), was the exact same string that I originally pass into the `url` variable...

So my question is as follows:

"What the ****?"

P.S. All input to this scenario is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) You didn't show us the code that is calling this function, or the value being passed as `url`. 2) Your code is wrong. You `catch` when no exception can be raised. If the function fails, it returns NULL, and you use `GetLastError()` to find out why). 3) Your `catch` throws a variable to which nothing assigns a value (AKA uninitialized). Fix those things, find out what `GetLastError` returns, and then edit your post to include the appropriate error information. When in doubt, always read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If the code you posted works, great. If it doesn't, your handling of that failure is totally wrong. Has nothing to do with "polite ethics" - the code you posted is flawed, and therefore any information you provide about the failure is suspect. *Fix the code so it's valid*, and then try to debug it - that's the way to "fix the problem". If you don't want to do that, you're wasting both your time and ours.

Comment: You are still trying to `catch` an exception that is never thrown. Get rid of the `try/catch` completely, and only call `GetLastError()` immediately after a function actually fails.

Comment: You ignored everything I said. Calling the function **does not raise an exception**, so your entire `try..catch` is simply a wasted effort. **Call the function, compare the return value to NULL, and if it is NULL call GetLastError() and see what you get.** I don't know how to say that any clearly. You **cannot** use try..catch to handle an error that **does not raise an exception**. Here's an idea - start over. See [How to create a minmal, complete and verifiable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), edit your question to include one that we can actually use, and go from there.

Comment: No, you didn't (until after my last comment, as the revision history shows). You're simply shooting in the dark now. A call to `GetLastError()` is meaningless if you **don't use the return value**. When you get serious about trying to get help by actually following the information you're given, I'll reverse my close vote. Until then, this is a waste of time. See the link in my last comment, and do what it says. Until then, I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: @AndrewPeters: Is this your **real** code copy/pasted from your project?  I doubt it. Your variable names do not match, for starters. You are assigning the result of `InternetOpenW()` to a variable named `hi` but are then passing a variable named `hInet` to `InternetOpenUrlW()` and `InternetCloseHandle()`. And you are assigning the result of `InternetOpenUrlW()` to a variable named `hu` but are then passing a variable named `hUrl` to `InternetCloseHandle()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error handling inside of `get_user_request()` is wrong, and your concatenation of `request_url` is also wrong.  The code should look more like this instead:

```
void DisplayWinInetError(LPCWSTR FuncName)
{
    DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    DWORD dwLen;

    std::wostringstream ErrorMsg;
    ErrorMsg << FuncName << L" failed!";

    if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR)
    {
        dwLen = 0;
        if (!InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&dwErrorCode, NULL, &dwLen) &&
            (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER))
        {
            ++dwLen;
            std::vector<wchar_t> msg(dwLen);
            if (InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&dwErrorCode, &msg[0], &dwLen))
                ErrorMsg << L'\n' << std::wstring(&msg[0], dwLen);
            else
                ErrorMsg << L"\nUnable to retrieve WinInet error message! Error: " << GetLastError();
        }
        else
            ErrorMsg << L"\nUnable to retrieve WinInet error message! Error: " << GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMsg << L" WinInet Error: " << dwErrorCode;

        LPWSTR lpMsg = NULL;
        dwLen = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwErrorCode, 0, (LPWSTR)&lpMsg, 0, NULL);
        if (dwLen > 0)
        {
            ErrorMsg << L'\n' << std::wstring(lpMsg, dwLen);
            LocalFree(lpMsg);
        }
        else
            ErrorMsg << L"\nUnable to retrieve System error message! Error: " << GetLastError();
    }

    MessageBoxW(NULL, ErrorMsg.str().c_str(), L"WinInet error", MB_OK);
}
```

```
void get_user_request(LPCWSTR url)
{
    HINTERNET hInet, hUrl;

    hInet = InternetOpenW(SUBSCRIBER_USER_AGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInet == NULL)
    {
        DisplayWinInetError(L"InternetOpenW");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, url, "Opening url", MB_OK);

        hUrl = InternetOpenUrlW(hInet, url, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
        if (hUrl == NULL)
        {
            DisplayWinInetError(L"InternetOpenUrlW");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, "We're in", L"OK", MB_OK);

            // ...

            InternetCloseHandle(hUrl);
        }

        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
    }
}
```

```
std::wstring request_url = L"http://example-site.com/user/<user-id>/?id=" + string;
get_user_request(request_url.c_str());
```

Comment: I added some more text to `DisplayWinInetError()`.  If it cannot retrieve a system error message, it will now say why.